# Should i use backend for simple API calls?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, spring, frontend, backend

let's say i want to call an API from my frontend application in something like react. The API that i want to call is an external API provided by someone else. The thing is, I need to specify the API-key in header, so should i just make the call using react or should I use something like Spring Boot to make my own API that will call the external API and then pass the data to my react app? How about API-key protection in just plain frontend apps?

Answer (score 4):

A best practice would be not to share your API keys in public, otherwise any malicious party can use the API key on behalf of you. I think it would be better to configure your API keys in the back end, and access that back end from your front end app.